# Polymorphism fundamentals

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm studying inheritance and polymorphism now and I've came across the concept that the compiler will evaluate (using reflection?) what type of object is stored in a base-type reference in order to decide what method to run upon calling a method with an override.

So for example:

```
class Shape
{
    public virtual void Draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing shape...");
    }
}

class Circle : Shape
{
    public override void Draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing circle...");
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    Shape theShape = new Circle();
    theShape.Draw();
}
```

The following will be output:

```
Drawing circle...
```

It's always been my understanding that on declaring any type of object it's a way of sort of designating memory for that specific type of object. So `Int32 i = 2l;` would mean that I have now put memory aside as a sort of 'placeholder' for an integer. But in the code above I've put memory aside for a Shape but it can infact reference/store an object of type Circle!?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All class variables in C# (and in Java) are actually only *references* - in contrast to the so-called primitive types (e.g. int, float) and structs; the actual space for the `Circle` object is reserved when you write `new Circle()`, `Shape theShape` only reserves space for the reference!

Any reference variable can hold a reference to all derived types; the actual resolution of which method to call (if it is declared `virtual`) happens by using virtual method tables *at runtime* (not via Reflection).

To explain what polymorphism can be used for (quoting [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29)):

> [It] allows values of different data types to be handled using a uniform interface.

The common interface for the Shape objects, in your case would be the `Draw()` method. It would make perfect sense to have a list of Shapes, and calling the `Draw()` method on each of them to display them. Meaning, that in order to view all Shapes, your program wouldn't need to take care what kinds of Shapes are stored in this list - all the proper `Draw()` methods would be called automatically.

Every class variable automatically being a reference is one of the big differences of C# (and Java) to languages like C++, where you can decide where you want your variable to live; for a Circle to be of value type (in C++), you'd write:

```
Circle circle;
```

If you instead want to point to it, you'd write

```
Circle * circle = new Circle();
```

Java and C# don't have an explicit sign making a variable a "pointer" or "reference" - simply every variable which should hold an object is a pointer/reference!

Also note that (e.g. in C++) you can only use polymorphism if you use pointers or references; that's because value types can just be accessed as what they were declared, and not more; with references and pointers, when your actual variable is only referencing to / pointing at something, it can point to a number of things (whatever the compiler allows it to point to).

Comment: But I'm referencing an object of a different type!? I understand that because of inheritance they are obviously related but despite that the Circle object potentially has more properties and methods than the Shape so could be quite different. I would've thought this'd be syntactically incorrect. Why would you ever need to do this? You'd just do Circle circle = new Circle(); surely??

Comment: you are referencing an object of a *derived* type, that's perfectly possible, that's what polymorphism is for.

Comment: > Why would you ever need to do this?

So that you can write code against the Shape interface without worrying about the specific type of Shape being used. If all you want to do is Draw () something you don't need to worry about the Shape being a Circle, Square, Triangle etc.

Comment: The `new` keyword has nothing to do with the storage location nor does it have anything to do with whether the type is a reference type or value type.  There is also very little value in thinking about the heap and stack.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

Answer (score 17):

> I'm studying inheritance and polymorphism now and I've came across the concept that the compiler will evaluate (using reflection?) what type of object is stored in a base-type reference in order to decide what method to run upon calling a method with an override.

The *compiler* does no such evaluation; the compiler is done executing long before the code runs. The *runtime* evaluates what type of object is referred to in order to decide which virtual method to call.  It does not do so using Reflection.

What the compiler evaluates is *what virtual method slot should be used when the method is called at runtime.* The compiler issues instructions that say "runtime, when this code runs, interrogate this object on this slot, and see what method is stored in that slot, and execute it".

It is educational to see how you might implement virtual methods in C# if C# did not have them built-in. See [my three-part series of articles on that](https://ericlippert.com/2011/03/17/implementing-the-virtual-method-pattern-in-c-part-one/).

> It's always been my understanding that on declaring any type of object it's a way of sort of designating memory for that specific type of object.

Now would be a good time in your education to start using words like "declaring", "object" and so on, correctly. Objects are not declared. *Types* are declared. *Variables* are declared.

So, it has been your understanding that declaring a local variable of a given type is a way of designating memory for that specific type of object.  Which is almost correct. If the type is a *value type* then that is correct. If the type is a *reference type* then the local variable of that type is storage that contains a *reference to other storage* that actually contains the object.

That is *absolutely fundamental* to C#, so make sure that you understand that. A local variable of type string does not contain a string. It contains a *reference* to a string; the string is somewhere else entirely and the reference refers to that location.

> In the code above I've put memory aside for a Shape but it can in fact reference/store an object of type Circle!?

It can store a *reference* to a Circle, yes, because a Circle is a kind of Shape and therefore a reference to a Circle may be used where a reference to a Shape is needed. It cannot store a *Circle* because a Circle is not *a reference to a Shape*.

If you have a notebook that contains the addresses of your friends, it might contain a reference to a unit in an apartment building, and it might contain a reference to a house. *The notebook does not contain an apartment building or a house*. Apartments and houses are both kinds of dwellings; your notebook contains references to dwellings.

Suppose a friend buys some land, builds a house, and sends you their new address. You do not need to allocate space in your notebook *for the house*. The city zoning department already allocated space for the house to be built somewhere else. You need to allocate space in your notebook *for the address of the dwelling*. The fact that a house is a kind of dwelling is what makes it legal to put the address in your notebook.

When you create an object that is an instance of a reference type, the runtime is the zoning department -- it takes care of allocating the storage for the actual object. The constructor "builds the house". The local variable is allocated to store the *reference* to the storage for the actual object.

Value types do not have reference semantics; rather, a variable of value type contains the actual object. That's why value types are called "value types" and reference types are called "reference types"; because a variable of value type stores the actual object and a variable of reference type stores a reference to an object that is somewhere else entirely.

I'm not sure that that answers your question because you don't seem to actually ask a question in your question. What is your question?

Answer (score 9):

```
class Contact {
  public string FirstName;
  public string LastName;
}

class Customer : Contact {
  public int OrderNumber;
}
```

[image]

When a method that expects a reference to a Contact is actually given a reference to a Customer, it still works because the Customer reference is a reference to a Contact as well.

Comment: Right ok, but then supposing I have the following declaration:

Contact contact = new Customer();

Would it then not be incorrect to write contact.OrderNumber??

Comment: you can't access OrderNumber doing that because the variable that points the Customer object is a "Contact" and it does not know anything about the implementation of Customer even if in memory there is a Customer Object. But if you cast it will work:  ((Customer) contact).OrderNumber = 5;

Answer (score 4):

The compiler doesn't understand it with *reflection*, it uses [Virtual Method Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) in order to find a pointer to a correct method to call, in the moment of it invokation.

Reflection is a *tool* for us, developers to obtain runtime information from given instance of object or type and not more.

Compiler goes a lot farther then that.

Answer (score 4):

`I've put memory aside for a Shape but it can infact reference/store an object of type Circle!?`

No, you are not correct here. When you do `Circle()` the memory that will be allocated here will be based on Circle class not Shape.

What you are doing here is you are creating a pointer of Shape Class and using that pointer you are pointing to object/memory of circle class. As through polymorphism you can point object of child class(Circle) through base class pointer (shape) that's why you are able to write

`Shape shape = new Circle();`

Comment: So would it then not be incorrect to reference shape.CircleProperty;?? Where CircleProperty is defined in the Circle class?

Comment: You won't be able to do it because Shape reference will only know about those properties which are public in Shape class. You can hold reference of Circle class in Shape pointer but it doesn't mean it will allow you to access public properties of Circle class

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a `Shape`, you're only setting aside the memory that will point to the object once it is created (you're creating a reference).

When you instantiate a `Circle`, the memory is consumed and the space you reserved with your declaration now points to your `Circle`.

As for calling the appropriate method, the runtime does not use Reflection at all. All information is stored in the [Virtual Method Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) and resolved when the call is made.

Answer (score 3):

You've allocated memory for a Circle by calling new on the Circle class.  You simply stored it into a Shape object.  This is possible because the Circle class contains a Shape object in a way as its base.

When you do the following line:

```
Shape theShape = new Circle();
```

You're saying create a Circle object and use a Shape object to point to it.  Since you're pointing to an object of type Circle, the override function for Draw() is called.

Look into the slicing problem to see what happens when you don't do this with reference types.

Answer (score 3):

In C# or more generally in .NET there are two types of objects: value types and reference types. Classes are always reference types. So the Shape you are assigning is just a reference or pointer, not a full block of memory to a shape.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but based on this I thought then it would only be possible to reference a parent from a child, as the child potentially has 'extra' properties and methods. So I assumed Circle circle = new Shape(); would be correct as circle then has the capacity for the properties and methods that the base Shape class holds plus more? It seems that, despite the circle being a derived class, I'm sort of disregarding the correct way to reference and object by using a reference of a different type?

Answer (score 3):

> It's always been my understanding that on declaring any type of object it's a way of sort of designating memory for that specific type of object.

In the case of a reference, you're only designating memory for the reference, which has the same size for any type of object (it's the size of a memory address).

The `new` expression will do the memory allocation for the actual object.

When you call `theShape.Draw()`, it's the .NET runtime that decides which actual method will be called; in this case the one for `Circle`. (The compiler cannot make this decision in general.)

Answer (score 3):

When declaring something as

```
Shape theShape;
```

you are telling the compiler that "theShape" will contain an object that is a `Shape` or can pretend to be one (ie because its a child). In this way you are saying that you can call any methods, properties, etc. on `theShape` that exist on the `Shape` object.

When you say:

```
Shape theShape = new Circle();
```

then you can be considered to be saying the above and in additionally saying that theShape is actually this new `Circle` object. Obviously we know that `Circle` will happily execute any of the methods, properties, etc. of Shape so this is perfectly OK.

If we were then to say:

```
theShape.CircleMethod();
```

Then things would go wrong. Although *we* know that theShape is a `Circle` the compiler doesn't know this. All we have told it is that its a `Shape` and that doesn't have a `CircleMethod` method on it anywhere so the above call is invalid.

If you are wondering why this is the case then think of the following code:

```
public void doSomething()
{
    Shape theShape = getShape();
    theShape.CircleMethod();
}

public Shape getShape()
{
    return new Circle();
}
```

The getShape method will return a circle but in this you can hopefully clearly see that calling CircleMethod is not allowed. The doSomething() method might not even know that circles exist (for example because these methods are in different assemblies) so it can only possibly work by treating the contents of theShape as a Shape, no matter what is actually inside.

I notice that somewhere in comments you say that you would expect `Circle circle = new Shape();` to be the way it would work.

Hopefully the above might explain why not. If not then hopefully another analogy will help.

Others have said that circle is just a reference. Imagine it to be a remote control where the declaration tells you what buttons the remote control has. In my original example our remote control called `theShape` has buttons on it for all the methods on `Shape` since this is how it was declared. When you press a button on the remote control it calls the method on the real object that it is pointing to. You might consider the remote control to be incomplete because there are lots of things that are on `Circle` that we don't have buttons for but the key thing is that all the buttons on control will work because `Circle` supports them.

In the example `Circle circle = new Shape();` our remote control has all the buttons for `Circle` but clearly when we press the button for `CircleMethod` then the Shape object that we are pointing our remote at has no idea what to do. And this is why that doesn't work.

As for why you want to do this. My second example is probably a good example of why. You might be getting the Shape from another method (eg one that might read a user input where they select Circle or Rectangle) and all you want to do is draw the selected shape for the user. You don't need to know which one they chose because you know they are both Shapes and that Shapes have a Draw method so you can just call that.

P.S. I know that some of this is very similar to things said elsewhere but I felt they were all focussing on technical aspects where I've tried to go more by analogy of how it works than the technical things like heaps and stacks which I don't care much about most of the time even though I consider myself a pretty good programmer. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there's a difference between value types and reference types.
When you declare a reference type (an instance of your Shape class, for instance), memory is allocated on the stack, which will contain a reference to a memory slot on the heap.

Also, a Type object will be created on the heap; once you initialize your `Shape` variable with an instance of `Circle`, a Circle object will be created on the heap, and it will also have a 'type pointer' to the Circle Type object.

When calling [the overriden] virtual `Draw` method, the CLR knows which implementation has to execute, because it can find the correct type via the type pointer.

For more in-depth information, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S8) article.

Answer (score 2):

The memory is allocated when `new Circle()` is executed so you have a `Circle` in memory !